# How to request a random 3 rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I request a random 3 rows (or as close to truly random as is possible) in pure SQL?

I try this way :-

```
select * from feedtable ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 3
```

But some time show me duplicate row , And some time show me 2 rows not 3 rows.

Why !

Comment: Not really sure why you get back 2 rows instead of 3, but **random doesn't mean unique/distinct**.

Comment: Any ideas why he is sometime seeing 2 rows instead of 3?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . EIther there are only two rows in the table or the processing of the result set is incorrect.

Comment: Here's a nice description of how to select random rows: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query you can use to remove duplicates from showing up in your result set:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM feedtable
GROUP BY (col1, col2);
ORDER BY RAND() DESC
LIMIT 3
```

This assumes that you only have two columns, which probably is incorrect, but you can add all the column names from `feedtable` into the above query.

Comment: What is your actual query?

Comment: `select * from feedtable ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: That won't work.  You need to `GROUP BY` the columns in order to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You should probably need to add the column random to your table before 'Order by'.
At least it make sense to me, and it works.

```
SELECT *, RAND() AS R
FROM feedtable 
ORDER BY R DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: i try this `SELECT *, RAND() AS weburlfeed FROM feedtable ORDER BY weburlfeed DESC LIMIT 3` but still return duplicate row

Comment: Ok, so you have duplicate rows in your feedtable. and for solve that: (1) You would have to 'group by' your 'key(s) column(s)', or (2) You need to clean up your data

Comment: Are you have any example or test my query ??

Comment: i try this and not return any row `SELECT weburl, id, name FROM $feedtable GROUP BY (weburl, id, name) ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: I recommend you to debbug by part. (1) "SELECT * FROM feedtable" check if everything is ok and see what are you key columns (2) "SELECT keycolumn1, keycolumn2  FROM feedtable GROUP BY (keycolumn1, keycolumn2)" check if there is nor duplicates (3) "SELECT keycolumn1, keycolumn2  FROM feedtable GROUP BY (keycolumn1, keycolumn2) ORDER BY rand()" check if the order is random and (4)  add "limit 3"... Tell me where you find the errors (sorry my english)

Comment: "SELECT * FROM feedtable" this query its work good and return my data